# Getting error on WL.Logger.send in production server

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst

After setting the native capture to true I am calling WL.Logger.send() and getting a error as

"After calling send the server (url of the server) it responded with 200 and "

```
{ "errors" :["Runtime :adapter name must be specified"],"isSuccessfull": false,warnings :[],"info":[] }
```

Note: I have deployed my WLClientLogReceiver adapter in the production server .Also getting an error like "unable to move wl.log to wl.log.send"

Comment: I need some more information.  What is the server and client version?  I strongly suspect your client is built from 6.1.0.1 WL studio but your server is still 6.1.0.0.  Regarding the "unable to move" message... you said "native capture to true" and you're calling "WL.Logger.send()", but are you actually logging anything?  If not, then it's possible nothing has been captured, and nothing is available to send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the versions conflicts of your client and server.
If so re deploy your WAR file with the correct version of your client.